# Cannot find symbol in Java. [Compiler error]

Tags: java, symbols

```
SlotMachine.java:76: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable slot
location: class MyFrame.pullHandler
```

Code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

class SlotMachine
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    { 
       MyFrame f = new MyFrame();
    }
}

class MyFrame extends JFrame
{
    JTextField r1 = new JTextField("---",10);
    JTextField r2 = new JTextField("---",10);
    JTextField r3 = new JTextField("---",10);



    JButton pull = new JButton("Pull");
    JLabel result = new JLabel("Not Played Yet");

public MyFrame()
{   

  JTextField [] slot = new JTextField[3];
  slot[0] = new JTextField("---",10);
  slot[1] = new JTextField("---",10);
  slot[2] = new JTextField("---",10);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(400, 400);  //replace with pack();?
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Slot Machine - By: ");

    add(panel);
    panel.add(slot[0]);
    panel.add(slot[1]);
    panel.add(slot[2]);
    panel.add(pull);
    panel.add(result);

    pull.addActionListener(new pullHandler());

}

class pullHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent pull)
    {
        int ban = 0;
        int cher = 0; 
        int mel = 0;
        int plays = 0;

        for(int count=0; count< 3; count++) //repeats three times, giving three random values
        {
            Random rand = new Random(); 
            int numRoll = rand.nextInt(3);  //0,1,2 values



        if  (numRoll==0)
            {
                //Bannana
                slot[0].setBackground(Color.yellow);    //I want to replace the 1 with the counts, so if it is the second loop, it would set it for the second box.
                ban++;
                /*slot[count]*/r1.setText("Banana");        
            }

            if (numRoll==1)
            {   
                //cherry
                r2.setBackground(Color.red);
                cher++;
                r2.setText("Cherry");
            }

            if (numRoll==2)
            {
                //Melon
                r3.setBackground(Color.green);
                mel++;
                r3.setText("Melon");  
            }
        }

        plays++;
        result.setText("Played " + plays);  //why don't I keep getting new values when I click "Pull"?

    }
}



}
```

I'm trying to use the slot[] array instead of r1/r2/r3 in my pullhandler class.
I tried reading through old posts, but could not find anything that was quite like my problem.

Comment: Go read up on variable scope.

Comment: The variable `slot` is local to the `MyFrame` constructor, and isn't known to `pullHandler`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of the scope of the constructor, the variable `slot` has no meaning.  If you want it to be accessed in other methods, move `slot` to the field level, with the `JTextField` variables.

Comment: the problem Is that whenever I move it outside the constructor I get this: `SlotMachine.java:63: illegal start of type
      slot[2] = new JTextField("---",10);
                                       ^
SlotMachine.java:63: <identifier> expected
      slot[2] = new JTextField("---",10);
                                        ^
SlotMachine.java:63: ';' expected
      slot[2] = new JTextField("---",10); `

Comment: Why can't you move `JTextField [] slot = new JTextField[3];` out of the constructor?  That's all you *can* move, anyway.

Comment: Ahhh, I think that was my problem! I shouldn't have been  moving the "slot[0] = new JTextfield("---",10); part! Thanks Makoto!

Answer (score 0):

`JTextField [] slot = new JTextField[3];` should be created outside `MyFrame()` constructor

To make it available to `pullHandler` you should also try making `slot` as `static`